# TypeScript compiler doesn't complain with this generic constraint

Tags: generics, typescript, constraints

```
class Stub
{

}

interface IListener<T>
{
    method( e : Event<T> ) : void;
}

class Event<T>
{
    target : T;
}

class Listener implements IListener<Stub>
{
    method( e : Event<boolean> ) : void
    {

    }
}
```

Is there any reason why TS compiler doesn't complain ? 'boolean' violates the interface contract. Stub type is specified in the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is because TypeScript is *structurally typed*. The following works (which is a simplification of your code sample:

```
class Stub
{

}

let foo:Stub = true; // Allowed ... `boolean` has all the member that a Stub has
```

However the following will fail:

```
class Stub
{
    someMember: string;
}

let foo:Stub = true; // Error. A boolean doesn't have `someMember` which should exist on a `Stub`
```

The reason for this is *developer* convenience.

Here is more discussion : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is due to the fact your Stub class does not expect anything which is fulfilled by basically every other type (incl. your boolean example). If you add e.g. x:number to your stub it will be flagged as error then.